# How do you add a Paypal "Buy Now" for order emails processed from backend?

Tags: orders, email, paypal, custom, email-templates

We are using magento CE 1.9. PayPal integration has been done for the front end.

When an is order created from the back end, the customer receive an email. I was looking to put a pay now PayPal button in the email body.

1.Sales person receive call from customer. 
2. Sales person logged in to the back end, creates a quote. Sends to customer. 
3. Customer replies back via email, quote accepted. 
4. Sales person converts quote to order. Sends order to customer from the back end via email.

Requested feature : when customer receives email with order, a "pay now"  PayPal button should be in the email body. Client clicks on "pay now" goes to PayPal page with order information and totals. Pays for order. Information return to back end that order has been paid.

I would appreciate any help :)

Thank you

Comment: Usually the confirmation is sent after the payment, am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't think this one would get posted, got an error in the process. I have another question similar with more details. Basically an order created from the back end, the customer receive an email. I was looking to put a pay now PayPal button in the email body.

Comment: Edit your question and add this information. Someone voted to close it but it's actually a good question(with the part you left out)

Comment: Vote to re-open - the voting reward system to close / open questions is ridiculous.

Comment: I just edited the question with more information. Hope it's more clear now. Thank you.